# How to change the form to the conventional layout

Tags: html, css, forms, vue.js

If a form is made using HTML/CSS tag (Vue):

```
<div class="is-h">
    <div class="is-aligned mb-1">
        <a @click="tooltips.groupSize.active = !tooltips.groupSize.active">
            <b-icon icon="help"></b-icon>
        </a>
        <span class="hps-1">People Traveling:</span>
    </div>
    <b-select v-model="form.groupSize" required>
        <option :value="i" v-for="i in 20" v-text="i"></option>
    </b-select>
</div>
```

How is it possible to "translate" it to the conventional `<input>` type of form, so it could be tracked by external services, like HotJar (which only detects standard forms)?

Comment: Translate it on the fly programmatically or a one off text editor change?

Comment: Those components are most likely rendered as input and select elements already.

Comment: @Bert they are, but HotJar doesn't detect them probably because it's going through `vue`

Comment: I imagine you'll have to look into server side rendering.